# Folder returning null when called

Tags: java, android

I am trying to assign a folder in my android Documents folder to a File rootDir, whose files would be stored in an array.

```
String path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS.toString()+"/Route Tracker";
    File rootDir =   new File(path);
    File fileList[] = rootDir.listFiles();
    String theNamesOfFiles[] = new String[fileList.length];
```

The error is being shown of the array theNamesOfFiles[]

But I am getting an error - *java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array*

Attempt to get the length of null array says that my fileList array is empty, but I don't understand how.
I have all the permissions needed in the manifest file, and the Route Tracker folder which I am calling also has 2 CSV files in it.

Comment: the array is empty

Comment: What do you mean? And I updated the post, please check again and solve my problem.

Comment: The fileList is empty. hence array of theNamesOfFiles is empty

Comment: From the documentation of `listFiles()`: Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Comment: On newer Android versions you need to request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous